# Compiling Swift source files issue with creating dictionary

Tags: swift, performance, dictionary, compilation

I am creating a dictionary in swift and it is taking a very long time (20 min) to compile

```
import Foundation

extension Renter {
    var dictionaryRepresentation: [String: Any]? {
        guard let email = email,
            let zipCode = wantedZipCode,
            let city = wantedCity,
            let state = wantedState,
            let country = wantedCountry,
            let creditRating = creditRating,
            let firstName = firstName,
            let lastName = lastName,
            let id = id
            else { return nil }

        var dictionaryRepresentation: [String: Any] = [UserController.kEmail: email,
                UserController.kZipCode: zipCode,
                UserController.kCity: city,
                UserController.kState: state,
                UserController.kCountry: country,
                UserController.kCreditRating: creditRating,
                UserController.kPetsAllowed: wantsPetFriendly,
                UserController.kSmokingAllowed: wantsSmoking,
                UserController.kWasherDryer: wantsWasherDryer,
                UserController.kGarage: wantsGarage,
                UserController.kDishwasher: wantsDishwasher,
                UserController.kBackyard: wantsBackyard,
                UserController.kPool: wantsPool,
                UserController.kGym: wantsGym,
                UserController.kFirstName: firstName,
                UserController.kLastName: lastName,
                UserController.kMonthlyPayment: Int(wantedPayment),
                UserController.kID: id,
                UserController.kBedroomCount: Int(wantedBedroomCount),
                UserController.kBathroomCount: wantedBathroomCount,
                UserController.kBio: bio ?? "No bio available",
                UserController.kStarRating: starRating,
                UserController.kMaritalStatus: maritalStatus ?? "Not specified",
                UserController.kCurrentOccupation: currentOccupation ?? "No occupation yet",
                UserController.kWithinRangeMiles: withinRangeMiles,
                UserController.kBankruptcies: bankruptcies,
                UserController.kCriminalHistory: criminalHistory ?? "",
                UserController.kDriversLicenseNumber: driversLicenceNum ?? "",
                UserController.kDriversLicensePicURL: driversLicensePicURL ?? "",
                UserController.kEvictionHistory: evictionHistory ?? "",
                UserController.kIncome: income ?? 0,
                UserController.kIsStudent: isStudent ?? false,
                UserController.kIsVerified: isVerified ?? false,
                UserController.kPreviousAddress: previousAddress ?? "",
                UserController.kReasonsForLeaving: reasonForLeaving ?? "",
                UserController.kSchool: school ?? "",
                UserController.kStudentID: studentID ?? "",
                UserController.kStudentPhotoIdURL: studentPhotoIDURL ?? ""]

        guard let profileImageArray = self.profileImages?.array as? [ProfileImage] else { return dictionaryRepresentation }

        let imageURLs = profileImageArray.flatMap({$0.imageURL})

        dictionaryRepresentation[UserController.kImageURLS] = imageURLs

        guard let occupationHistory = self.occupation?.allObjects as? [Occupation] else { return dictionaryRepresentation }

        let occupationDicts = occupationHistory.flatMap({ $0.dictionaryRepresentation })

        dictionaryRepresentation[UserController.kOccupationHistory] = occupationDicts

        return dictionaryRepresentation
    }

}
```

I've tested it and I know it is the creation of this dictionary because I've tried removing half of the dictionary and it compiles much faster. Does anybody have some tips on how to speed this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning a literal value to a dictionary is buggy in the current versions of Swift and likely to trigger compilation issues. A quick workaround is to avoid literals and do it the long way.

```
   var dictionaryRepresentation =  [String: Any]()
   dictionaryRepresentation[key1] = value1
   dictionaryRepresentation[key2] = value2
   ...
```

It generates more code but it compiles really quickly.

I give a complete code example that compiles very quickly in this manner... I am sure you can modify your own code similarly...

```
import Foundation

func getDict(email : String, zipCode : String, city: String, state: String,  country: String, creditRating: String,
     wantsPetFriendly: Bool, wantsSmoking: Bool, wantsWasherDryer: Bool, wantsGarage: Bool, wantsDishwasher: Bool,
       wantsBackyard: Bool, wantsPool: Bool,  wantsGym: Bool, firstName: String, lastName: String,
      wantedPayment: NSNumber,  id: Int,  wantedBedroomCount: NSNumber, wantedBathroomCount: NSNumber,
      bio: String?, starRating: Int, maritalStatus: String?, currentOccupation: String?,
      withinRangeMiles: Bool, bankruptcies: String, criminalHistory: String?,
      driversLicenceNum: Int?, driversLicensePicURL: String?, evictionHistory: String?,
      income: Int?, isStudent: Bool?, isVerified: Bool?, previousAddress: String?, 
      school : String?,studentPhotoIDURL: String?,
      studentID: String?, reasonForLeaving: String?) -> [String: Any] {
                var dictionaryRepresentation =  [String: Any]()
                dictionaryRepresentation["kEmail"] = email
                dictionaryRepresentation["kZipCode"] = zipCode
                dictionaryRepresentation["kCity"] = city
                dictionaryRepresentation["kState"] = state
                dictionaryRepresentation["kCountry"] = country
                dictionaryRepresentation["kCreditRating"] = creditRating
                dictionaryRepresentation["kPetsAllowed"] = wantsPetFriendly
                dictionaryRepresentation["kSmokingAllowed"] = wantsSmoking
                dictionaryRepresentation["kWasherDryer"] = wantsWasherDryer
                dictionaryRepresentation["kGarage"] = wantsGarage
                dictionaryRepresentation["kDishwasher"] = wantsDishwasher
                dictionaryRepresentation["kBackyard"] = wantsBackyard
                dictionaryRepresentation["kPool"] = wantsPool
                dictionaryRepresentation["kGym"] = wantsGym
                dictionaryRepresentation["kFirstName"] = firstName
                dictionaryRepresentation["kLastName"] = lastName
                dictionaryRepresentation["kMonthlyPayment"] = Int(wantedPayment)
                dictionaryRepresentation["kID"] = id
                dictionaryRepresentation["kBedroomCount"] = Int(wantedBedroomCount)
                dictionaryRepresentation["kBathroomCount"] = wantedBathroomCount
                dictionaryRepresentation["kBio"] = bio ?? "No bio available"
                dictionaryRepresentation["kStarRating"] = starRating
                dictionaryRepresentation["kMaritalStatus"] = maritalStatus ?? "Not specified"
                dictionaryRepresentation["kCurrentOccupation"] = currentOccupation ?? "No occupation yet"
                dictionaryRepresentation["kWithinRangeMiles"] = withinRangeMiles
                dictionaryRepresentation["kBankruptcies"] = bankruptcies
                dictionaryRepresentation["kCriminalHistory"] = criminalHistory ?? ""
                dictionaryRepresentation["kDriversLicenseNumber"] = driversLicenceNum ?? ""
                dictionaryRepresentation["kDriversLicensePicURL"] = driversLicensePicURL ?? ""
                dictionaryRepresentation["kEvictionHistory"] = evictionHistory ?? ""
                dictionaryRepresentation["kIncome"] = income ?? 0
                dictionaryRepresentation["kIsStudent"] = isStudent ?? false
                dictionaryRepresentation["kIsVerified"] = isVerified ?? false
                dictionaryRepresentation["kPreviousAddress"] = previousAddress ?? ""
                dictionaryRepresentation["kReasonsForLeaving"] = reasonForLeaving ?? ""
                dictionaryRepresentation["kSchool"] = school ?? ""
                dictionaryRepresentation["kStudentID"] = studentID ?? ""
                dictionaryRepresentation["kStudentPhotoIdURL"] = studentPhotoIDURL ?? "" 
  return dictionaryRepresentation;
}
```